# how do I calc the number of possible 350nt fragments from a 1500nt string?

Tags: math, probability

Say I have a nucleotide string on 1500nt, e.g.

ATTGCCGATATGCCCGTAGCTAGC... etc.

and we say that every 'T' is a possible cutting point and we assume equal ratio of A, T, G and C and equal distribution, that is:

ATCGATCGATCGATCGATCG... etc.

So every 4th position is a possible cutting site.

For each cut I'll make a 350nt length fragment, however the left-over fragments can be smaller, e.g. making a cut at position 71, would leave behind a fragment of 71nt length.
(A bit like when baking Christmas cookies, where you push out shapes with a metal frame and there is always some dough left behind).

Q1, how many unique pieces of 350nt can I possibly make?

Q2, how many of those pieces would contain both position 200 and 490?

I realize this is more a math question then a coding question, but I really hope someone will be able to help me anyway.

Please note that I asked ChatGPT about this and get vastly different answers whenever I regenerate the answer, so please don't do that in order to answer here, I need an actual human who can think about the solution :)

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming question; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. The general topic is called "combinatorics" and you might be able to find relevant resources by a web search for that term, maybe combining it with some domain-specific words, e.g. "genomics" or something.

Comment: thank you so much for refering me to the right forum and the helpful additions !